# Make jQuery Datepicker keep navigating on persistent keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have the jQuery Datepicker on my app. I have searched the docs over and over for an option to enable continued keyboard navigation on persistent keypress.

By default, `Ctrl+Arrow` will move the date one step in any of the 4 directions. (I have actually extended this functionality to happen also on `Arrow` keys, as it seems more intuitive to me).

What I now need:

To have the current date selection keep moving during one continuous keypress, rather than require intermittent keypresses. The utility of this behaviour becomes more obvious when you need to navigate back 3 or more decades.  Continuous navigation is actually the behaviour of the Windows calendar (near the system tray), as well as one Dynarch Calendar that I have been using for ages.

Since there seems to be no native option, any workaround, or plugin would be acceptable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you intend to write one yourself?  I imagine that it may be a little difficult to find a plugin that does this - this seems pretty specific.  Have you tried writing anything?

Comment: Is it that specific? I thought that would have been everybody's gold-standard on keyboard navigation, and calendars in particular!

Comment: Okay, an update. It turns out that the behaviour in question is a browser-variable one! Using `Chrome` and `Safari`, the navigation is continuous on persistent keypress. I had only used `Opera` version 11 before posting the question.